# I cannot send the new version to revision in App Store Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I've changed in Xcode the version name and the version code, archived for TestFlight and App Store Connect. The previous version was 4.19.0 and i want to upload the 4.20.0 but when I try to send to revision it appears this:

[image]

It says in spanish that i must select a version.

[image]

[image]

What i'm doing wrong? Please help me is the first time i upload a version to the Apple App store

Answer (score 0):

I needed to select the version in the Compilation sector.